# using DIFF with a remote system

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync, diff

I would like to get the difference between two directories (not files), lets say *dir1* on a local system and *dir2* which is located on a remote server.
From what I could find on the internet, the "best" option is to use `rsync`, as such:

```
rsync -rvc --delete dir1/    user@ip:/home/user/dir2
```

After checking the difference (if there is any) then I need to `rsync` again from the local to the remote so the two directories are identical.
Now in order to do that, I need check the exit value of this command and proceed accordingly (I am doing this all in a shell script). I originally did this with the `diff` command which would allow me to check the exit value (0 for no difference and 1 for a difference between the directories). But with `rsync` the exit code simply returns if the command run successfully, which is not what I need.

Here is what I need to do:

1. check if two directories are different (get the return value 0 or 1)
2. if not different then nothing happens
3. if different, then using `rsync` the directories are synchronized

p.s: I did this locally (from one dir to another dir) and it works perfectly with `diff`, not with the remote system though.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: why not use rsync straight away ? `-u` updates only newer files and if there is nothing to update, rsync will not do anything

Comment: What I mean is: rsync has the compare already built in, no diff necessary

Comment: Why do you want the `--delete` option if you're just checking for differences? Could you read rsync's output and look for messages indicating "different" or "same"? Or just run `diff` to check if different?

Comment: Yes Robert , but I have a shell script that checks whether the two directories or similar, if YES then i can run the rsync command to synchronize dir 1 and 2 but if not then nothing happens.
What really matters to me is the exit status of the check; for instance with DIFF if there is no difference then 0 is returned or else 1.
Now with RSYNC the exit status is something totally different; once I get a return status then I can go on with other statements in the script.

Comment: Yes Xen2050, well noted, --delete in the check is irrelevant. Thank you